# How to select content from inner children in ng-content

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-ngcontent

I have a component called `tab` which has `<ng-content select="[tabItem]"></ng-content>`

Sometimes `tabItem` is inside other child components. My problem is Angular selects the content from direct children, not inner children (app-my-tab), is there any way to do it?

app.component.html

```
<app-tabs>
    <div tabItem>
        Tab 1
    </div>
    <div tabItem>
        Tab 2
    </div>
    <app-my-tab></app-my-tab>
</app-tabs>
```

my-tab.component.html

```
<div tabItem> 
  My Tab
</div>
<div>
  Other content
</div>
```

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-ng-content)

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for deep selection.
I thing it is logical, because:

1. understand and real code easily
2. easy to debug.

If you want really do that use ***ngIf** in app-my-tab.

***To use `*ngIF`:***

1. All element in `app-tabs` must have `tabItem` attribute
2. send your condition to show/hide some other element in to `app-my-tab` component. and `app-my-tab` receive it as `@Input()` property
3. in `app-my-tab` html use `*ngIf` to show or hide some element

**Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-ng-content-2gyttv?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: my goals is to display all 3 tabs there, I didn't get how ngIf can solve the issue, can you please kindly fork the stackblitz and propose your solution there

Comment: But what if the target is not a child of another component? Meaning, `<ng-content select="#parent .child"></ng-content>` alongside `<div id="parent"><span class="child"></span></div>`.

Comment: You have to send a template of the content somehow to the component, that will show tabs. then use *ngTemplateOutlet to render the template. (`<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRefOfContent"></ng-container>`)